# Avoiding screen rotation in viewport meta property (web mobile)

Tags: viewport, meta, landscape-portrait

Is it posible to avoid screen rotation on web mobile with the viewport meta property? Our website should only be viewed in portrait mode always.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is totally dependent on your user agent and the platform on which it is runnung.
But you can make sure that they wouldn't mess in your page, if it is written in the head section properly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Not worked, can you please suggest any more from meta tag or CSS